# vim: How to search for a hard-coded string (not regex)?

Tags: vim

In order to search for a string in Vim, I click "/" and then type the word that I have to search. Vim looks at this string as regular expression. I want to know how to search a string, as it it, and not treat it as a regex.

Comment: `/\<string\>/`, this could achieve your goal.

Comment: you should provide an example. Have a look at `:h magic`

Comment: @paul  I type "/5/15/" in order to search for the string "5/15" and it doesn't work properly. Only when I type "/5\/15/" I get the string "5/15"

Comment: @CrazySynthax a trick might be `?5/15?`, you can do so without escaping `/`. :)

Comment: @paul That searches in the wrong direction.

Comment: @phd I would call it `wrong` direction, its just the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

[Search commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#search-commands) always search for [patterns](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#search-pattern) (also known as regular expressions). You can make patterns more or less [magic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) but cannot turn metacharacters completely off. If you have a fixed string you have to escape the characters that vim understands as metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

With the *very nomagic* mode of Vim's regular expressions ([`:help /\V`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CV)), only the backslash is a special character that needs escaping.

So, prepend `\V` to your literal search, and (either manually or via `escape(pattern, '\')`) duplicate any backslashes. The following turns a "regular" search in to a literal one; you could define a mapping for that:

```
:let @/ = '\V' . escape(@/, '\')
```